# Where to begin with using Facebook's PHP SDK to create events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to use Facebook's PHP SDK to create/update/cancel events on our Facebook Page, whenever they are added/modified/deleted within the "calendar of events" database table on our web site.

Where do I even begin with this?  I have the SDK installed, but I am having a really hard time figuring out how to register my own custom app and install it to my Facebook user account.  I did manage to get an App ID and App Secret, and I also created a minimal canvas and indicated which persmissions the app needs.  But, for the life of me I can't figure out how to install the app on my FB user account.

I don't want to make the app available to others, and I don't even want to access it while I'm logged into Facebook.  I just want to be able to do something like $fbapi->createEvent() within my own code on my own site.

Also, do I need to have an authenticated Facebook user session/cookie when calling the API to create the event?  It seems to me that would eliminate the possibility of creating events via a command-line PHP cron job.

I feel like I am understanding bits and pieces of this, but there are gaps in my understanding and I'm not seeing how all the pieces fit together.  Any direction would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First play around with the Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer  so you can understand better how the Graph is used. From there you can then learn about the PHP SDK http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php and how to do the same things you did with the explorer tool.  Events are here documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/